# my nextAll() wont function

Tags: jquery, html, traversal

I know that this is already questioned out but my code can't get to what i wanted to.

```
<table id="dataTable" style="width: 450px;">
    <tr>
        <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk[]" /></td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><INPUT type="text" style="text-align:right;width:50px;" name="qty[]" id="qty[]" /></td>
                    <td><INPUT type="text" onchange="display_details(this, this.value, 'item')" name="bar[]" id="bar[]" /></td>
                    <td><INPUT type="text" readonly="1" id="item[]" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="left"><div style="border:1px solid #000;width:425px;float:left">asdasdasdasd</div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This block of code is inside a container which will show up upon calling the function.

And here's my js code:

```
function display_details(er, bar,ex){  
    var id = $(er).nextAll('input').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

This code above doesn't work. I also tried this code:

```
var id = $(er).css('background-color', 'red');
```

And that works perfectly fine.

This is the code I have also tried to run.

```
var id = $(er).nextAll('div:first').css('background-color', 'red');
var id = $(er).nextAll('input:first').css('background-color', 'red');
var id = $(er).nextAll('input').first().css('background-color', 'red');
var id = $(er).nextAll('div').first().css('background-color', 'red');
```

None of them did anything.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is er, bar and ex??? clarify

Comment: @theCodeParadox The function is called from this - `onchange="display_details(this, this.value, 'item')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.nextAll()` applies to the siblings of the current element. You input does not have any siblings so nothing is happening.

You need to move back up the tree using `.parent()` and then find the elements you want to update from there.

This works for the next inputs:

```
function display_details(er, bar,ex){  
   var id = $(er).parent().nextAll('td').find('input').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/jMwyG/1/

Comment: i tried it and it works.. but i tried applying it to the div but nothing happens.

Comment: * i tried double parent and nextAll and worked.. thanks a lot mr dalton.. :D